# How to find the jni libraries which is packaged in a AAR in Android Studio with Android plugin for gradle 2.3.1？

Tags: android

My project must use a AAR for a dependency. 
The AAR packages some classes and a jni library (e.g.libdemo.so). 
The jni library is used as LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES in my project.

With Android plugin for gradle 2.2.3, I take the following two ways:

*1.Unpackaged AAR manually and put libdemo.so in the directory related to Android.mk:*

```
 ###########################prebuild libdemo.so############################## 
 include $(CLEAR_VARS)
 LOCAL_MODULE    := libdemo LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libdemo.so
 LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH) include
 $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

*2.AAR is unpackaged in build/intermideate. So I set the path to libdemo.so in Android.mk:*

```
 ###########################prebuild libdemo.so############################## 
 include $(CLEAR_VARS)
 LOCAL_MODULE    := libdemo 
 AAR_LIB_PATH = $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../build/intermediates/exploded-aar/vm/jni/armeabi
 LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(AAR_LIB_PATH)/libdemo.so 
 LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH) 
 include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

But for Android plugin for gradle 2.3.1, the rule changed：

> Build cache: stores certain outputs that the Android plugin generates
>   when building your project (such as unpackaged AARs and pre-dexed
>   remote dependencies).

I specify a path relative to the gradle.properties file.

```
 android.buildCacheDir=buildcache
```

It works and I can see the caches but I can't find libdemo.so directly buildcache:

[image: buildcache]

I can't use the WAY 2 now.
Is there any more convenient method to link the jni library?

Answer (score 0):

For projects using the Android NDK, it is easier to use Gradle experimental version to implement JNI functionality into your application.

The `*.so` library file is accessible after extracting the AAR package. Here is a sample gradle function to extract an AAR to the corresponding build path holding `*.so` files:

```
task extractSo(type: Copy) {
    from zipTree("${project.rootDir}/libraries/name-of-aar-package.aar")
    into "${project.rootDir}/libraries/"
    include "jni/**/name-of-so-library.so"
}
```

Define the `extractSo` task in the base `build.gradle` file for the entire project. To use Gradle experimental version, you must also define the classpath to Gradle experimental in the base `build.gradle` file like so:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

   dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.9.0'
    }
}
```

To invoke the `extractSo` task, you must define a dependency on this function in the build.gradle file for the project module which requires it. Here is some sample code that does this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 25
        buildToolsVersion = "25.0.2"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.my.sample.package.ndkapp"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 19
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 24
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
        }
    }
    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'))
        }
    }
    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "nativeclass_jni"
        cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
        cppFlags.add("-I" + file("src/main/jni").absolutePath)
        // Add the necessary headers required in cpp code.
        cppFlags.add("-I" + file("${project.rootDir}/libraries/headers").absolutePath)

        stl = "gnustl_shared"
        // Add the necessary project .so files for all architectures.
        ldFlags.add("-L" + file("${project.rootDir}/libraries/jni/arm64-v8a").absolutePath)
        ldFlags.add("-L" + file("${project.rootDir}/libraries/jni/armeabi-v7a").absolutePath)
        ldFlags.add("-L" + file("${project.rootDir}/libraries/jni/x86").absolutePath)

        ldLibs.addAll(["log", "android", "EGL", "GLESv2"])

        // Specific the particular .so files this sample links against.
        ldLibs.add("name-of-so-library")
    }
    android.productFlavors {
        create ("fat") {
            // This sample builds all architectures by default. Note that if you
            // only want to build for a specific architecture, you need to
            // remove the appropriate lines below. You also need to remove the
            // .so files from the apk using
            // "packagingOptions {exclude('lib/armeabi-v7a/*')}" in the android
            // section.
            ndk.abiFilters.add("arm64-v8a")
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
            ndk.abiFilters.add("x86")
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // specify any Android java modules this project depends on
    // For example:
    // compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}

// Extract the *.so libraries packaged in AAR files.
build.dependsOn(':extractSo')
```

To ensure that your Java code can access the native functions in the *.so files and your native Android code, you must now load the library in your main activity like so:

```
static {
     // Loading your native code module
     System.loadLibrary("nativeclass_jni");
     // Loading your extracted *.so library
     System.loadLibrary("name-of-so-library");
}
```